# Using Katalon to Run A Mobile Automated Test

Tags: mobile, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I'm having issues running a simple log in, log out automated test using Katalon and Kobiton. Any time I run the script it gets stuck at the beginning and never runs. I'm trying to figure out what needs to be done for this to go through. Any help would be much appreciated.

As you can see below this is the code used and the resulting message received through Katalon.

Code:

```
import static com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory.findCheckpoint
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory.findTestCase
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory.findTestData
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.Checkpoint as Checkpoint
import com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords as CucumberKW
import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords as Mobile
import com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling as FailureHandling
import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCase as TestCase
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestData as TestData
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject as TestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords as WS
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI
import internal.GlobalVariable as GlobalVariable

Mobile.startApplication('kobiton', true)

Mobile.tap(findTestObject('android.widget.Button0 - ALREADY HAVE AN ACCOUNT'), 0)

Mobile.tap(findTestObject('android.widget.Button0 - ALREADY HAVE AN ACCOUNT'), 0)

Mobile.tap(findTestObject('android.widget.EditText0 - Email'), 0)

Mobile.setText(findTestObject('android.widget.EditText0 - Email (1)'), '', 0)

Mobile.setText(findTestObject('android.widget.EditText1 - Password'), '', 0)

Mobile.tap(findTestObject('android.widget.ImageView7'), 0)

Mobile.tap(findTestObject('android.widget.Switch0 - OFF'), 0)

Mobile.tap(findTestObject('android.widget.Button3 - LOGIN'), 0)

Mobile.tap(findTestObject('android.widget.Button0 - '), 0)

Mobile.tap(findTestObject('android.widget.TextView12 - Logout'), 0)

Mobile.closeApplication()
```

Message:

```
(Stack trace: com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to start app at: (Root cause: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:07:36.161Z'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: SwipeableAndroidDriver)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain.stepFailed(KeywordMain.groovy:36)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.internal.MobileKeywordMain.stepFailed(MobileKeywordMain.groovy:40)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.internal.MobileKeywordMain.runKeyword(MobileKeywordMain.groovy:23)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.builtin.StartApplicationKeyword.startApplication(StartApplicationKeyword.groovy:51)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.builtin.StartApplicationKeyword.execute(StartApplicationKeyword.groovy:40)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:53)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords.startApplication(MobileBuiltInKeywords.groovy:74)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords$startApplication.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at Script1541159043147.run(Script1541159043147.groovy:16)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:183)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:108)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:294)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:285)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:264)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:256)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:200)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:99)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:90)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at TempTestCase1541422340602.run(TempTestCase1541422340602.groovy:22)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:263)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:518)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:507)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processOnce(GroovyMain.java:653)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.run(GroovyMain.java:384)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.process(GroovyMain.java:370)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processArgs(GroovyMain.java:129)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.main(GroovyMain.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:109)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:131)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add real file.apk into the code

```
Mobile.startApplication('C:/user/...', true)
```

then you will success

You could find the APIdemos.apk file in this path
"C:\Users\username\Katalon Studio\NewTest1.prj\androidapp\APIdemos.apk"

Answer (score 0):

This error generally occurs for cloud applications when path is not properly provided. Instead of 'kobiton', you need to provide the id or the storage path from kobiton for the application you have uploaded on their site.

For example:

```
Mobile.startApplication('kobiton-store:71', true)
```

or provide the path in capability as:

```
capabilities.SetCapability("app", "kobiton-store:71");
```